# How much space for /home on a hadoop cluster?

Tags: home, cluster, hadoop

What is a reasonable size to provide for a /home partition for 100 users on a hadoop cluster?

Assume that a landing zone has been provided to store files/data for ingestion into the cluster, so the /home partition would be non-project type storage.

Answer (score 1):

This is primary opinion based: it depends on what you expect the users to do with that space.

My opinion is that the only reasonable usage for a `/home` partition would be to build software which is supposed to be run in the cluster, and as testing area for such software (so that people can know whether a program will run or not in the cluster without scheduling a job). Estimating the size for that really depends on details of which software you expect them to compile. Without knowledge about that I would go for ~500gb

You would want to balance this with the size of the the disks in first place anyway.